# how to convert result from CompletionStage

Tags: java, playframework-2.6, completion-stage

I access an API and it returns the result as success, but I want to convert result to type `integer`, when I try, it show me the error

> cannot convert from completionStage to integer

My code

```
WSRequest req1 = ws.url("https://localhost/v1.0/mobile/user/profile")
            .addHeader("Authorization", token);
    CompletionStage<? extends WSResponse> rsp1 = req1.get();
    int a;

    return a = rsp1.thenApply(rs->ok(rs.asJson().findPath("user").findPath("id")));
```

Comment: You almost certainly need to call `.toCompletableFuture().get()`, if all you have is a `CompletionStage`.

Comment: ok thank you, this is very usefull for me